# How to add a query param to the URL in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am trying to add a query param when I type some value in a input text and hit the ENTER key but I am unsure where to add it so it works. All I need is my URL to be `/search?searchTerm=something` and the reason why is because if I click in any link and move to a different page but then go back using the browser button since there is no searchTerm I lose the search results and that is not right. See the following code snippet:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useState, KeyboardEvent } from 'react'

export const SearchPage = ({ locale }: { locale: string }) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.query.searchTerm) {
            handleSearch(router.query.searchTerm as string)
        }
    }, [router.query])

    const handleSearch = async (searchTerm: string) => {
        setSearchTerm(searchTerm)
        const searchResult = await getSearchResult(searchTerm, locale)
    }

    const handleSearchKeydown = async (
        event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    ) => {
        if (
            event.key === 'Enter' &&
            searchTerm.trim() !== '' &&
            searchTerm.length >= 3
        ) {
            await handleSearch(event.target.value)
            event.target.value = ''
        }
    }

    return (
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="text" onKeyDown={handleSearchKeydown} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The code I need to introduce and I am not sure if this is correct, I am open to ideas here is as follow:

```
router.replace({
  query: { ...router.query, searchTerm: searchTerm}
})
```

> Note: `searchTerm` is equivalent to `event.target.value` since is the value the user typed in the input.

I have tried to add it inside the `useEffect` and inside the `handleSearchKeydown` right after the `await` but I get a weird behavior where the page keeps loading itself in an infinite loop. I can't get what I am doing wrong here, can I get some ideas or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerreplace)

> ### router.replace
>
> Similar to the replace prop in next/link, router.replace will prevent adding a new URL entry into the history
> stack.

if you want to add the url to the history stack, you need to use

```
router.push(`search?key=${searchTerm}`)
```

the reason why you are getting infinite loop is, your dependency is `router.query` object. when you set the state inside  `handleSearch`, it rerenders the component (state change rerenders the component), you create new `const router=useRouter` object so you have a new `router.query` object which is a `useEffect` dependency so your component rerenders. if you set the dependecy as

```
[router.query.searchTerm]
```

this should avoid infinite rerendering